# TestNG How to reinitialize DataProvider before it is used in each test case?

Tags: java, spring, testng

I recently came across a problem regarding using testNG's dataProvider when I'm doing api tests. My question is, how should I reinitialize the data provided in the dataprovider before each time it is fed into the test case?

```java
@DataProvider(name = "testDataProvider")
public static Object[][] testDataProvider() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(2);
    params.put("a", "foo");
    params.put("b", "bar");
    return new Object[][]{
        {params}
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testDataProvider")
public void testCase01(Map<String, String> params) {
    params.put("a", "oof");
    assertEquals(params.get("a"), "oof");
}

@Test(dataProvider = "testDataProvider")
public void testCase02(Map<String, String> params) {
    assertEquals(params.get("a"), "foo"); // this won't pass
}
```

I want both tests to pass. However, currently if `testCase01` runs before `testCase02`, `testCase02` won't pass because I have already overwritten the value of `params.get("a")`. How do I make sure that my DataProvider always returns the hard-coded value in its definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be a problem if you are using the latest version of TestNG (`7.0.0-beta7` as of today).

Here's a sample that demonstrates this.

```java
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Sample {

  @Test
  public void versionConfirm() {
    String file = TestNG.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile();
    String actualVersion = new File(file).getParentFile().getName();
    assertEquals(actualVersion, "7.0.0-beta7");
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "testDataProvider")
  public static Object[][] testDataProvider(Method method) {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(2);
    params.put("a", "foo");
    params.put("b", "bar");
    params.put(method.getName(), Integer.toString(params.hashCode()));
    return new Object[][] {{params}};
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "testDataProvider")
  public void testCase01(Map<String, String> params) {
    params.put("a", "oof");
    assertEquals(params.get("a"), "oof");
    assertTrue(params.containsKey("testCase01"));
    assertFalse(params.containsKey("testCase02"));
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "testDataProvider", dependsOnMethods = "testCase01")
  public void testCase02(Map<String, String> params) {
    assertEquals(params.get("a"), "foo"); // this won't pass
    assertFalse(params.containsKey("testCase01"));
    assertTrue(params.containsKey("testCase02"));
  }
}
```

Here as you can see, I am forcing `testCase01()` to run before `testCase02()` by using `dependsOnMethods` and it still works fine.

Comment: Yes I realized it was the problem with my api testing framework, not TestNG. Thank you!